# Create new ASP.NET 5 project for existing Azure App Service

Tags: asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I've finally gotten around to familiarizing myself with Azure.  I've created several App Services on a new App Service Plan.  I've created a SQL Server instance and a SQL Server DB.  My intention is to create new MVC sites, one for each App Service I created.  I got the Azure SDK all set up and went about trying to create my first site, but now I'm stuck.  It seems Microsoft expected me to create the projects in Visual Studio first, and allow the Azure SDK to create a corresponding App Service in Azure for the new projects.  This isn't what I've done.  So, I've encountered a screen where Visual Studio is asking me to put in details (Web App Name, Resource Group, App Service Plan) for the new App Service, but it doesn't let me choose from a list of existing App Services.

How can I associate the project I'm creating in Visual Studio with the existing App Service I already created in the Azure Portal?

[image: This is the dialog I encountered while creating a new Web Application in Visual Studio and selecting the option to host in Azure. Notice there's a text box to enter a new App Service (Web App) name, but no drop-down to select previously existing App Services]

This is the dialog I encountered while creating a new Web Application in Visual Studio and selecting the option to host in Azure. Notice there's a text box to enter a new App Service (Web App) name, but no drop-down to select previously existing App Services.

Comment: this is possible.  maybe something isn't set up as you expect? do you have the correct subscription selected? could you maybe show a screenshot?

Comment: See the accepted answer.  If you are at the screen shot above, you are in the wrong place.  You can't connect your project to an existing Azure App Service while creating the project in Visual Studio (at the time of this writing).  Create the project first, and then use the Publish dialog to connect it to Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Web Apps can be created in either direction. You should be able to create them either via Visual Studio or directly in the Azure Portal.

I'm assuming that you've already performed the following steps:

1. In Solution Explorer, right-click web app project.
2. In popup menu, select "Publish"
3. Select Azure subscription to see if any Web Apps exist.

From here on forward, you should be able to create a new Web App or select an existing Web App. Since you're not seeing your existing Web App, let's try to troubleshoot.

1. In the Publish dialog, create a new Web App (in Visual Studio).
2. In the Azure Portal, check to see if that Web App was created.

In case you have more than 1 subscription (e.g. free, BizSpark, MSDN from work), this will confirm whether you're looking at the same subscription in both places.

I've included a screenshot below to show you that I have multiple subscriptions, each of which contains a different set of Web Apps.

[image: Azure publish screenshot]

Hope that helps!

Comment: Ah, my approach was the issue.  You accessed this differently.  I was trying to do this while creating a new ASP.NET web application.  In other words, I was right clicking the Solution and then Add >> New Project.  In the following dialogs, I checked "Host on Azure" which brought up something similar to your screen shot, but there was no option to access existing App Services, only create a new one.  If I simply create it without trying to host it, then I can go back and do what you suggested and it works just fine.  Thanks.

Comment: I am still wondering about something.  I don't see a "Publish" option for the entire solution, just individual projects.  If I have a solution with lots of projects (an ASP.NET site and some supporting class libraries), so when I publish the web app project, how will Azure/Visual Studio know that the DLLs for the class libraries need to be published, too?  And will those be able to run as part of the App Service, or will they require an Azure WebJob or...?  As you can tell, I'm very new to Azure.

Comment: Hi bubbleking, glad to hear it works for you now. :) Anything referenced in your web project should be included in the deployment. To avoid going off-topic here, feel free to email me at shchowd at microsoft dot com or post a new question on StackOverflow, if you feel it would help the community.